# Can there exist a second cube root of $z$ located in the first quadrant?

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose $w$ is located in the first quadrant and is a cube root of a complex number $z$. Can there exist a second cube root of $z$ located in the first quadrant?

I'm not sure of this question. I'm a little confused. Can someone help me with this?

I don't have idea of how solve this.

Comment: The three cube roots of a nonzero complex number form the vertices of an equilateral triangle centred at zero in the Argand diagram.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If

$w^3 = z \ne 0\tag 1$

and

$w = re^{i\theta}, \tag 2$

then

$r^3 e^{i 3 \theta} = w^3 = z, \tag 3$

with

$r^3 = \vert r^3 e^{i3\theta} \vert = \vert z \vert, \tag 4$

$r$ uniquely determined since it is positive real.  On the other hand, since we have $z$ in the first quadrant,

$3 \theta = \arg(z) \in \left [0, \dfrac{\pi}{2} \right ), \tag 5$

there are $3$ values of

$\theta \in [0, 2\pi) \tag 6$

which satisfy (5):

$\theta = \dfrac{\arg(z)}{3}, \; \dfrac{\arg(z)}{3} + \dfrac{2\pi}{3}, \; \dfrac{\arg(z)}{3} + \dfrac{4\pi}{3}; \tag 7$

with these $\theta$, only one value of $w$ as in (2) lies in the first quadrant; the angle $2\pi/3$ is simply too large to allow more than one value of $w$ per quadrant, since

$\dfrac{2\pi}{3} > \dfrac{\pi}{2}. \tag 8$

If, on the other hand, we look at

$w^n = z, \; n \ge 5$

then multiple solutions per quadrant are permitted.

Comment: I think it is $w$ that is in the first quadrant, that is $θ=\arg(w)∈[0,π/2)$. Which does not change that the main point of the $120°$ angle distance remains true.